# Why my Review queue for Low quality posts appears this way?

Tags: support

A few minutes ago my review queue for low-quality posts was as in the figure below. After clicking on the red bullet I expected to see the flagged post but I couldn't see any, i.e. the queue was cleared.

Perhaps this is normal behaviour but I wonder what it means.

[image]

Comment: The way that this part of the UI works is very mysterious to me, also! Because this is about how the review queue works network-wide (across all sites, including Cross Validated), it might be best to do a search of the main SE Meta site and then ask a question there if you can't find a thread about it.

Comment: While reviewing (from phone mostly), I also faced the same but never thought deeply about it attributing it to some lagging in that by the time, I clicked, it was reviewed. But would be keen to know if there is any specific going on.

Comment: I think there's a lag between the dropdown menu and what shows up in the queue so that sometimes there's a discrepancy between them for a while.

Comment: In fact, just noticed, the lag remains for quite some time.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue right now.

Comment: 10 mins and still  counting.

Comment: still a red bullet. Posted this issue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385440/344965).

Comment: It has been one hour now. Either I am oblivious of the mechanism or something is fishy.